# How to use this code in python 3 version?

Tags: python, methods, syntax, format

I want to run this code in the python 3 but i can't.Whenever i try to run the code,i get the invalid syntax error.

```
age = 20
name = 'Swaroop'
print '{} was {} years old when he wrote this book'.format(name, age)
print 'Why is {} playing with that python?'.format(name)
```

Comment: Check this out https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Put parentheses around the `print` *function* calls.

```
print('{} was {} years old when he wrote this book'.format(name, age))
print('Why is {} playing with that python?'.format(name))
```

---

In Python2, `print` is a statement, and does not require parenthesis.

[In Python3, `print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), so it requires parentheses around its arguments.